# Does non-disclosure agreement still hold if i break contract before i start work?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, new-job, hiring-process

I received an offer from a company, say CompanyA, and am interviewing still with another company –  CompanyB.
CompanyA has a lot of clients one of which may well be CompanyB – CompanyA has a lot of clients in the sector that CompanyB is in. In fact, I interviewed with a client of CompanyA not long ago, and that’s the very client I’ll work on if I accept CompanyA’s offer.

A clause in CompanyA’s offer agreement is banning me to do anything with any of their clients for a full year, and I find this fair.

I don’t want to settle for anything before I hear CompanyB’s offer or see how things’ll be with them, and that’s another 5-6 days. But i have to say something to CompanyA in a day or 2. On the other hand, the start day of CompanyA is 2+weeks-- way after I’ll have known about CompanyB.

My question is – am i liable of 1yr non-disclosure if I break the contract before the start date?
So – i sign CompanyA’s offer, then break the agreement i signed before i start working with them and getting anywhere near confidential “zones”.

This may look like I’m juggling offers and it is in a sense. but the way i see is – i shouldn’t make such close timing and terms i can’t control dominate my decision re.a very big part of my life.

**Apart from all these** (maybe i should ask this as a separate Q ?) – CompanyA will conduct a security check on me after i sign the agreement and before i start. They aren’t telling what it is about despite my asking. And they’ll only send me the forms etc for that security check after i sign the agreement. Am i supposed to be concerned about this? Committing myself on the agreement before knowing how far they'll dig into my privacy isn't a comfortable "feeling", especially when they refuse to give a slightest hint.

//=======================

**UPDATE:**

NDA & offer letter are 2 separate documents to sign. NDA is referred to as ".. part of employment terms and conditions.. " and "..must be signed as a condition to employment ..". No other ref.to NDA in the offer.

there isn't a client list or anything specific like that on NDA. clients are broadly referenced as (and they have a lot of clients) --

> "*.. not to provide products/services that would compete with those of CompanyA..*"

didn't think this was significant before.
will check w/them and sign the agreement only, NDA to be signed "when it's time to start work"

Comment: What do you mean by a "disclosure agreement"? What you are describing in your second paragraph is a non-compete agreement, and the other thing that is typical is a *non*-disclosure agreement. A disclosure agreement would be something that required you to mention information and seems odd.

Comment: Actually that's very astute.

Comment: Why do you care about a 1 year non-disclosure agreement if you won't have started and therefore don't have any information to disclose anyway?

Comment: my experience on this site's been that there are 2 main perspectives going on -- employers and employees. and then there are Qs tapping the gray zones in between.

Comment: Is this a non-compete agreement or a non-disclosure agreement? They are completely different things.

Comment: @SimonB whats the diff? there's everything in it -- "don't show company documents to anyone", "don't take up anything directly/indirectly with any clients or affiliates"..

Comment: @ash__999 That sounds like it's both in one document.  A normal non-disclosure agreement is along the lines of "We will only show you our trade secrets if you agree not to pass them on to anyone else".  I have signed a few of them over the years, but none ever limited who I was allowed to work for.

Comment: @ash__999, It doesn't matter what they wrote on top of the document. What matters is what's written in the document itself. And what you have here is both a non disclosure agreement AND a non-compete agreement. How much will they be paying you during that one year? How many clients are listed? In what jurisdiction is this in? For instance, if you're in California, it's going to be very different than in other states. The same goes for the background check. The background check is going to be limited by the jurisdictions your future office is in and the position you're applying for.

Comment: Have you told Company B that you already received an offer from another company? If you haven't yet, do so. If they're afraid of losing you, this will speed up their process considerably. Can you post an excerpt of the non-compete clause and of the non-disclosure clause?

Comment: @SimonB i signed one like this before and didn't mind. but CompanyA has just about everyone among its clients

Comment: Non-compete and non-disclosure are two different things. You can be subject to one, both, or none.

Comment: Signing the offer then backing out will be seen as very unprofessional and will burn the relationship with A permanently, btw, regardless of the NDA/noncompete status.

Comment: @mxyzplk i'm doing this as an alternative to backing out altogether and i think is fair/reasonable to ask. if they don't like me enough for this, might be better it sinks. i don't feel so comfortable with their "leave yourself to our hands, everything will be alright"

Comment: Use whatever excuses you want, accepting an offer you know you’re going to back out of is seen as very poor professionalism.

Answer (score 11):

If you sign a contract, you are bound by the terms of the contract.  Does the noncompete say it’s contingent on actually starting work?  If not, then likely it is binding, but only a lawyer could tell you for sure after reading the contract.

You can either tell A you need more time (and tell B you need to move quickly) or take the bird in hand and sign with A.  But there’s no “accept and sign but weasel out” or “accept and don’t sign” options.

Comment: "If you sign a contract, you are bound by the terms of the contract"  that's completely wrong though!  many contracts are non-enforceable.  i wouldn't be at all surprised if a whacky "before you even work for us non compete" is legally void.

Comment: @Fattie If they didn't give the signer anything then I agree but I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: @Fattie an NDA is usually enforcable (some really weird clauses excluded), unlike a non-competition clause which is often unenforcable as most are way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not if the information was already public knowledge... "[T]here are numerous loopholes upon which an NDA may be challenged, such as where the definition of the “confidential information” can be shown to be “vague” or “overbroad.”  NDAs may also be unenforceable if one can show the “confidential information” is not really “confidential” and has been disclosed to others." From [The not so powerful non-disclosure agreement](https://www.mcmanislaw.com/blog/2018/the-not-so-powerful-non-disclosure-agreement-nda)

But I encourage you not to sign agreements which you believe are unreasonable or that you have no intention of keeping as there can be many negative consequences. For example company A could inform company B that you signed their agreement and then company B may decide you can't be trusted to keep your word and not to hire you.

Comment: Keep in mind that challenging a NDA is typically a legal procedure, brought about as an attempt to defend within a lawsuit.  This can be quite expensive, even if you are clearly going to win.

Comment: @EdwinBuck True. It can easily costs 5 figures.

Answer (score -1):

As a practical matter,

1. CompanyA is pressuring you to rush. Red flag.

Almost just on principle, I would tell them your decision would take longer (or, simply, don't reply inside their whacky "deadline")

Recall that the entirety of every action of a company is to make you feel that the company has power and you have no power. Every single interaction is based on that.

2. Given the details you have offered, CompanyA seems to want you to sign a noncompete well **before** actually joining the company. Just as with paying-for and getting-the-title to a house, it is something you do simultaneously with the fixed signed contract. This is beyond a red flag and just bizarre.

Recall that the entirety of every action of a company is to make you feel that the company has power and you have no power. Every single interaction is based on that.

Regarding the legal question of whether such a bizarre turn of events would be enforceable, I don't know and I don't think anyone does. **If you go to and ask a lawyer, they will just laugh and say obviously don't sign this until you are literally signing to join the company.**

3. Regarding the "mystery security check" we don't have all the details but it seems a bit strange. It would depend on the exact details and norms in the field.

Bottom line: just ignore their bizarre artificial "2 day" "deadline". Or, if you like, just politely reply with a two word email "Am waiting as other offers come in." But really just say nothing and wait your time.

(Regarding the "pre-deal noncompete" thing, just ignore it.)

Comment: Yeh the  "mystery security check"  is very odd if your doing a real security check you will know what's involved up front even for TS or DV clearance jobs.